# karma testing failing in directive

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following directive. This Directive will trigger after animation end triggers. I now just want to add test for this directive. I have created the test case for this. But it's failing. Can anybody help on this? [This is plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cKPOgVnrWYQdTIAHHTxE?p=preview)

```
angular.module('movieApp')
    .directive('animationend', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            animationend: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {

            var callback = scope.animationend(),
                events = 'animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd' +
                        'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd';

            element.on(events, function(event) {
                console.log('[animationend directive] callback');
                callback.call(element[0], event);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And my test case is

```
describe('Directive: animationend', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('movieApp'));

  var elements,
    scope,
    compile;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$compile_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = _$compile_;
    elements = angular.element('<div animationend="" ></div>');
    elements = compile(elements)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should trigger the callback once animationclass is added ', function () {

    scope.ctrl = {
      animationend: jasmine.createSpy('animationend')
    };
    scope.$digest();
    var events = 'animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd' +
                        'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd';
    angular.element(elements).triggerHandler(events);
    // element.trigger(events);
    expect(scope.ctrl.animationend).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });


});
```